# LibreOffice crashes (or hangs) 12.10 and 13.04

Tags: 12.10, 13.04, libreoffice

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 several months ago, but LibreOffice was entirely unusable.  Whenever I opened a document, spreadsheet, etc. it would crash or hang the desktop.  I waited for Ubuntu 13.04, hoping that this would be resolved, but the issue is the same.  Has anyone else seen this?  Any hints for getting past this?  Or do I need to go back to 12.04?

Comment: This is a bug report and should be reported. [Here](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/BugReport) is the link that explains how to report bugs.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be a raring ringtail bug because in one latptop Libreoffice works flawlessly, but in my computer it just behaves like the one Bob reported.

I had it reported in here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1179755